# WPF Grid Question, can I determinate the absolute position of something, which is positioned automatically in a WPF Grid?

Tags: wpf

I like to use a grid to position some objects in WPF, because it cares about the position and stuff. In addition, however I also like to be able to draw accross the cells with a Canvas.

I figured out that this can be done by embedding the grid in a canvas. However in order to connect two elements, I need then the absolute position in pixels.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

From code you can use the [`UIElement.TranslatePoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx) method.